# Selenium find element which have no attributes but have parents with same attributes

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find XPath of an element which has no attribute. It can only be identified by its parent's attribute. However, the parent also does not have unique attribute.

Eg: `//*[@id="btn"][1]/ul/li[2]/a/span`

Here there are 2 elements with `id=btn`. How do i get the 2nd element. The above syntax gives me 1st element.. However if i use:

```
//*[@id="btn"][2]/ul/li[2]/a/span
```

I get an error message 
**"The xpath expression '//*[@id="btn"][2]/ul/li[2]/a/span' cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement "**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you select those two first, then use brackets around and index them.

```
 (//*[@id="btn"]/ul/li[2]/a/span)[2]
```

By the way, it's not a good practice to have multiple elements sharing same ids, if you are the developer, may consider change them.

Comment: I know that.. And trust me i curse the person who developed the site :)